# NUC with 2 hdmi ports is switching after each restart

Tags: hdmi

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on the Intel NUC (BOXNUC7CJYHN2). This NUC provides 2 hdmi ports. After each restart I have to plug the screen to the other hdmi-port, to see the screen. BIOS screen is visible on both ports all the time. Means:

Starting the system, after having Ubuntu up and I migh not see the screen, I have to move screen-hdmi-plug from one hdmi port and plug it into the other port. When then restarting, after Ubuntu is up and running again, the screen is black and I have to plug screen to the other hdmi-port.

The start screen always appears on both ports.

Any idea about how to set a fixed port?

Comment: It might be worth updating the BIOS and turning off Consumer Electronics Control (CEC) from the BIOS menu. It's just a guess but it might be interfering somehow, info on that [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/mini-pcs/nuc-kits/NUC7xJY_TechProdSpec.pdf).

Comment: Nothing of these ideas were helping.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ports are being detected the same way each time, a manual port selection can be easily done with a script containing an xrandr command to activate the correct monitor.

If the port identities/labels are changing at each boot, you'll might be able to fix that with a UDEV rule.

Comment: As I am not a Linux expert, I ownde rhow to do it.

Comment: Open a terminal and enter xrandr - then reboot until the other monitor activates and do it again. Comparing the results should identify which event is occurring - either port identities changing or not.